# Running remote processes in Guest from VMware CLI

Tags: vmware

I am trying to run a script on a Windows Vista virtual machine with `vmrun` but I get an error.

Here is my command:

```
vmrun -gu *** -gp *** runProgramInGuest /path/to/Vista.vmwarevm "C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" "/c Z:\deploy\windows\ExtractFile.bat"
```

Nothing was done and the result is:

```
Guest program exited with non-zero exit code: 1
```

I tried to execute directly in Vista this and it works fine:

```
C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c Z:\deploy\windows\ExtractFile.bat
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the right syntax that works:

```
vmrun -gu *** -gp *** runProgramInGuest /path/to/Vista.vmwarevm -activeWindow -interactive cmd.exe "/c Z:\deploy\windows\ExtractFile.bat"
```

It seems that the `-interactive` is mandatory for the script to work.

And if you want to pass parameters to your script just append them after the script name and add an extra space (important):

```
vmrun -gu *** -gp *** runProgramInGuest /path/to/Vista.vmwarevm -activeWindow -interactive cmd.exe "/c Z:\deploy\windows\ExtractFile.bat param1 param2 "
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for this for a while ;)